# Can you change the behaviour of bitwise or on custom types?

Tags: python

[Since Python 3.10](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/) you can annotate types using `type1 | type2` instead of `Union[type1, type2]`, for example: `int | float`.

Can you change the behaviour of bitwise-or on custom types? I.e. if I create my own type:

```
class A(type):
    pass
```

I would like to customize the result of `A | int`, something like:

```
class A(type):
    __class_or__(cls, other) -> 'MyOwnCustomUnion': ...
```

Is that possible?

I have tried defining `__or__(self, other): ...` on my metaclass, but that doesn't do anything:

```
class A(type):
    def __or__(self, other):
        print(other)
        return super(A, self).__or__(other)


print(A | int)
# prints "__main__.A | int", does not print "<class 'int'>" as expected.
```

Comment: You'd need to implement `__or__` on the _metaclass_, inheriting `type`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have tried that, doesn't seem to work. could you provide an example where it works which I can test?

Comment: Please give a [mre]. Do you actually want A to already be a metaclass?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have added my attempt at doing exactly what you suggested.

Comment: You haven't implemented it on the metaclass _of A_ (which would have to be a meta-meta-class, I guess?) - currently that's `type`, which still has the conventional implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharper pointed out in the comments, it has to be implemented "one level above A", (sorry I don't know how to better phrase it.

This works:

```
class MyUnion:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


class A(type):
    def __or__(self, other) -> MyUnion:
        return MyUnion(self, other)


class B(type, metaclass=A):
    pass


print(B | int)
# <__main__.MyUnion object at 0x000001824C7B3040>
```